# mongodb db not showing up

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, rest

I am trying to use MongoDB for a REST API project. Yesterday, the db worked fine and it showed up in command prompt. Now, when I run db in my mongo terminal, my database does not show up. It even says that it connected to the MongoDB when I run my server which uses this code:

```
const connectWithRetry = () => {
    console.log('MongoDB connection with retry')
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/rest-tutorial", options).then(()=>{
        console.log('MongoDB is connected')
    }).catch(err=>{
        console.log('MongoDB connection unsuccessful, retry after 5 seconds. ', ++count);
        setTimeout(connectWithRetry, 5000)
    })
};
```

I'm new to this so I am kind of unsure what to do. The code works fine and when I register new users and send data to the database, I get my desired output. However, I am unable to see the stored data in command line. What can I do?

**EDIT AS REQUESTED**

mongo commands run:

**db**
test

**show collections**
(nothing shows up even though I submitted data. This is also the wrong db)

Comment: Can you share the commands you run in command line that aren't working? And can you include the output from `show dbs` and `show collections`?

Comment: @caffeinated.tech check edit

Comment: You should select database by use command like `use rest-tutorial` and then use find like `db.users.find()` where `users` is collection name, you may list collection name by command `show collections`

Comment: @ArifKhan I believe that's the solution, can you post it as an answer once OP replies?

Comment: @ArifKhan perfect thanks!